# correlation estimator variance

Tags: correlation

Consider I have realisations of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and I estimate their correlation thanks to the classic formula :

$$\rho=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_iy_i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\bar{y})^2}}$$

1- What is the variance of the estimator and how to calculate it?

2- Hypothesis tests use the t-statistic:

$$t=\frac{r\sqrt{n-2}}{1-r^2}$$

Why is that?

Any references or pointers to pdfs, courses, or textbooks with exhaustive treatments are welcome.

Thanks for help

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: OP - your definition of the sample correlation coefficient appears incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The variance of the sample correlation is not an easy question; nor is an easy general answer available. If you refer to:

- Stuart and Ord (1994), *Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics*, volume 1 - Distribution Theory, sixth edition, Edward Arnold

... an approximation is provide at eqn (10.17) (based on what is essentially the delta method) to the variance of a ratio $\frac{S}{U}$ (provided $S$ and $U$ are positive):

$$Var\big(\frac{S}{U}\big) \approx \big(\frac{E[S]}{E[U]}\big)^2 \big( \frac{Var(S)}{(E[S])^2} + \frac{Var(U)}{(E[U])^2} - \frac{2 Cov(S,U)}{E[S] E[U]} \big) $$

In your instance,

$$S = m_{11}  \quad \quad \text{and } \quad \quad U = \sqrt{m_{20} m_{02}}$$

where $m_{ab}$ denotes the sample central product moments.

They then apply this approximation in their *Example 10.6* to find an approximation to the variance of the sample correlation ... which is what you seek. The $\sqrt{}$ in $U$ poses further difficulties ... they appear to deal with the $\sqrt{m_{20} m_{02}}$ in the denominator by a further approximation (again via the delta method). In any event, an approximate solution is posited on these pages to a non-trivial problem as:

$$Var(r) \approx \frac{\rho^2}{n} \big( \frac{\mu_{22}}{\mu_{11}^2} + \frac14 \big(\frac{\mu_{40}}{\mu_{20}^2} + \frac{\mu_{04}}{\mu_{02}^2} + \frac{2 \mu_{22}}{\mu_{20} \mu_{02}}\big) - \big(  \frac{\mu_{31}}{\mu_{11}\mu_{20}} + \frac{\mu_{13}}{\mu_{11}\mu_{02}} \big) \big) $$

where $r$ denotes the sample correlation coefficient, $\rho$ denotes the population correlation coefficient, and $\mu_{ab}$ denotes product central moments of the population.